# How do I output the string connected to it's Uppercase length

Tags: java, string, loops, char

In this program I'm trying to create I have a method to take a string to count the amount of uppercase letters. At the end of the program I want to show the smallest amount associated with it's string and the max amount associated with its string which is where I'm having trouble. Is there a way to somehow connect or associate these together? Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please input a string:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = input.nextLine();
        String s2 = input.nextLine();
        String s3 = input.nextLine();
        int i1 = sumLetter(s1);
        int i2 = sumLetter(s2);
        int i3 = sumLetter(s3);


        int[] array = new int[3];
        array[0] = i1;
        array[1] = i2;
        array[2] = i3;
        Arrays.sort(array);

        System.out.println(s1 + " has a maximum number of uppercase: "+ array[2]);
        System.out.println(s3 + " has a maximum number of uppercase: "+ array[0]);


    }
    public static int sumLetter(String m) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length();i++) {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(m.charAt(i)))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to handle this, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "This string has FIVE uppercase characters within itself.";
  System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^\\p{javaUpperCase}]","").length());
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

This is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "This string has FIVE uppercase characters within itself.";
  int uppercases = 0;
  for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    uppercases += Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  System.out.println(uppercases);
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Now, assuming that you have this functionality (which you do) within some method:

```
public static int sumLetter(String m) { ... }
```

You want to associate the String with the uppercase length. Make a simple data class:

```
final class StringWithUppercaseSize {
  public final String string;
  public final int uppercaseLength;

  public StringWithUppercaseSize(String string, int uppercaseLength) {
    this.string = string;
    this.uppercaseLength = uppercaseLength;
  }

  public int getUppercaseLength() {
    return this.uppercaseLength;
  }
}
```

Now, you make an array of these objects:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s1 = input.nextLine();
String s2 = input.nextLine();
String s3 = input.nextLine();
int i1 = sumLetter(s1);
int i2 = sumLetter(s2);
int i3 = sumLetter(s3);
StringWithUppercaseSize[] sizes = { new StringWithUppercaseSize(s1, i1), new StringWithUppercaseSize(s2, i2), new StringWithUppercaseSize(s3, i3) };
```

Sort the array, by the uppercase size:

```
Arrays.sort(sizes, Comparator.comparing(StringWithUppercaseSize::getUppercaseLength));
```

Output the minimum/maximum uppercase string/lengths:

```
System.out.println(sizes[0].string + " has a minimum number of uppercase: "+ sizes[0].uppercaseLength);
System.out.println(sizes[2].string + " has a maximum number of uppercase: "+ sizes[2].uppercaseLength);
```

Input:

```
Abc
abc
aBC
```

Output:

```
abc has a minimum number of uppercase: 0
aBC has a maximum number of uppercase: 2
```

Here's my full test code:

> Main.java

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please input a string:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = input.nextLine();
        String s2 = input.nextLine();
        String s3 = input.nextLine();
        int i1 = sumLetter(s1);
        int i2 = sumLetter(s2);
        int i3 = sumLetter(s3);
        StringWithUppercaseSize[] sizes = { new StringWithUppercaseSize(s1, i1), new StringWithUppercaseSize(s2, i2), new StringWithUppercaseSize(s3, i3) };
        Arrays.sort(sizes, Comparator.comparing(StringWithUppercaseSize::getUppercaseLength));
        System.out.println(sizes[0].string + " has a minimum number of uppercase: "+ sizes[0].uppercaseLength);
        System.out.println(sizes[2].string + " has a maximum number of uppercase: "+ sizes[2].uppercaseLength);
    }
    public static int sumLetter(String m) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m.length();i++) {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(m.charAt(i)))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

> StringWithUppercaseSize.java

```
final class StringWithUppercaseSize {
  public final String string;
  public final int uppercaseLength;

  public StringWithUppercaseSize(String string, int uppercaseLength) {
    this.string = string;
    this.uppercaseLength = uppercaseLength;
  }

  public int getUppercaseLength() {
    return this.uppercaseLength;
  }
}
```

Finally, as a note, *don't* do this in code you intend to keep and maintain. There are plenty of ways to make things more readable and maintainable. For example, you can write actual getters/setters for your data class. You can make the public data members private to preserve information hiding. You can append user inputs into a List, and then use things like a for-each loop to create another List of uppercase sizes. You can go over both those lists with a for-each loop to create a List of `StringWithUppercaseSize`s. You can probably use a Stream with Collectors.maxBy to find the maximum elements instead of sorting, etc.

Comment: wow man thank you for explaining this so clearly. I'm going to learn more about objects they seem to make things way more easier.

Comment: hey man sorry to bother you again. I'm still trying to understand it a bit more clearly since I'm new to objects. Would you mind explaining each line if possible?

Comment: @Exrial Each line of which part?

Comment: the part after declaring int i3 in the main method. I'm having troubleunderstanding that array sizes.         StringWithUppercaseSize[] sizes = { new StringWithUppercaseSize(s1, i1), new StringWithUppercaseSize(s2, i2), new StringWithUppercaseSize(s3, i3) };                               is this a method and what does it do?

Comment: It is an array initializer. It says, "let `sizes` be a new array consisting of the elements: a new StringWithUppercaseSize taking parameters s1 and i1 in its constructor, a new StringWithUppercaseSize taking parameters s2 and i2 in its constructor, and a new StringWithUppercaseSize taking parameters s3 and i3 in its constructor". Then, `Arrays.sort` sorts the contents of `sizes` (which are the created `StringWithUppercaseSize`s) by the value returned from their `getUppercaseLength` method.